# Pygame banner not showing up on my game screen, what could be causing this issue?

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to make a game in Python using Pygame. The main part of the game is OK and running. But, the "Game Over" banner cannot be displayed whatever I've tried. My Class for the Banner, and my test code just to make Banner displayed is given below. What might be the problem? (I've already added a button in a similar way. It works but banner doesn't).

```
import pygame.font

class Banner:
    """A class to write info on screen."""
    def __init__(self, game, info):
        """Initializing the class."""
        self.screen = game.screen
        self.screen_rect = self.screen.get_rect()

        # Set the dimensions and properties of the banner.
        self.width, self.height = 400, 100
        self.banner_color = (0, 0, 0)
        self.banner_text_color = (255, 255, 255)
        self.banner_font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 48)

        # Build the banner and place it.
        self.b_rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, self.width, self.height)
        self.b_rect.center = self.screen_rect.center #(self.screen_rect.centerx, 150)

        self._prep_info(info)

    def _prep_info(self, info):
        """Turns info into a rendered image and centers text on the banner."""
        self.banner_image = self.banner_font.render(info, True, self.banner_text_color,
            self.banner_color)
        self.banner_image_rect = self.banner_image.get_rect()
        self.banner_image_rect.center = self.b_rect.center

    def draw_banner(self):
        # Draw blank banner and draw the info.
        self.screen.fill(self.banner_color, self.b_rect)
        self.screen.blit(self.banner_image, self.banner_image_rect)type here
```

```
import sys
from banner import Banner
import pygame

class Test:
    """A class for testing purposes."""
    def __init__(self):
        """Initializing test class."""
        pygame.init()

        # Create a display window.
        self.screen_color = (255, 0, 0)
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
        pygame.display.set_caption("Test")
        self.game_over = Banner(self, "Game Over")

    def run_test(self):
        """Start the test."""
        while True:
            self._check_events()
            self._update_screen()
            self._test_banner()

    def _check_events(self):
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()

    def _update_screen(self):
        self.screen.fill(self.screen_color)
        pygame.display.flip()

    def _test_banner(self):
        self.game_over.draw_banner()

# Main program
if __name__ == '__main__':
    test = Test()
    test.run_test()
```

Coded a banner to be displayed on screen, but it didn't.

Answer (score 1):

It is just a matter of the order. You have to call `pygame.display.flip()` after drawing the banner. You are actually drawing on a [`Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update) object. If you draw on the *Surface* associated to the PyGame display, this is not immediately visible in the display. The changes become visible, when the display is updated with either [`pygame.display.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update) or [`pygame.display.flip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip).

```py
class Test:
    # [...]

    def run_test(self):
        """Start the test."""
        while True:
            self._check_events()
            self._update_screen()
            self._test_banner()
            pygame.display.flip()              # <--- INSERT  

    def _check_events(self):
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()

    def _update_screen(self):
        self.screen.fill(self.screen_color)
        #pygame.display.flip()                   <--- DELETE

    def _test_banner(self):
        self.game_over.draw_banner()
```

The typical PyGame application loop has to:

- limit the frames per second to limit CPU usage with [`pygame.time.Clock.tick`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock)
- handle the events by calling either [`pygame.event.pump()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump) or [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get).
- update the game states and positions of objects dependent on the input events and time (respectively frames)
- clear the entire display or draw the background
- draw the entire scene (`blit` all the objects)
- update the display by calling either [`pygame.display.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update) or [`pygame.display.flip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip)